# when i try to run my flutter app it shows an error on info.plist

Tags: xcode, flutter, dart, info.plist

I wrote my app on a windos machine, then I moved it to mac. But I can´t run it on the mac while it is still working in the windos machine. The app is live in play store
this is the error :

> Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 13 Pro Max in debug mode...
> /Users/macair/Downloads/مجلد بلا
> عنوان/flutter_application_1/ios/Runner/Info.plist: Property List
> error: Found non-key inside  at line 6 / JSON error: JSON text
> did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not
> set. around line 1, column 0. /Users/macair/Downloads/مجلد بلا
> عنوان/flutter_application_1/ios/Runner/Info.plist: Property List
> error: Found non-key inside  at line 6 / JSON error: JSON text
> did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not
> set. around line 1, column 0. Running Xcode build... Xcode build done.
> 47.4s Failed to build iOS app Error (Xcode): unable to read property list from file: /Users/macair/Downloads/مجلد بلا
> عنوان/flutter_application_1/ios/Runner/Info.plist: The operation
> couldn’t be completed. (XCBUtil.PropertyListConversionError error 2.)
>
> Could not build the application for the simulator. Error launching
> application on iPhone 13 Pro Max.

this is my info.plist code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>Flutter Application 1</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>magic world entertainment</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>https</string>
    </array>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
    <key>CADisableMinimumFrameDurationOnPhone</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIApplicationSupportsIndirectInputEvents</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0):

AllowsArbitraryLoads should be inside a dict

```
            <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key> 
            <dict>
                    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
                    <true/>
            </dict>
```

Comment: it didn't work :
Info.plist: Property List error: Found non-key inside <dict> at line 10 / JSON error: JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set. around line 1, column 0.

Comment: Show your Info.plist
You still haven't got it right.